# Заменить каждый пятый элемент в векторе на '0' с помощью алгоритмов

Tags: c++, алгоритм, stl, vector

Есть вектор целых чисел. Нужно только с помощью стандартных алгоритмов STL заменить каждый пятый элемент на 0.

Пытался с помощью replace_if, но но там 3м параметром передается значение текущего элемента, но ведь значение нас не интересует, только порядковый номер который должен делится на 5 без остатка. Возможно есть способ достать именно номер элемента, а не его значение, с помощью итераторов можно как-нибудь? Или просто есть другой алгоритм для такой задачи.

Comment: integers.at( 5*i ) = 0;

Comment: А лямбдой отсчитать каждый пятый?...

Comment: Обязательно использовать только функции из <algorithm>?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate/
В этом примере есть генератор, он дает порядковый номер. Мне кажется, это можно использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типа

```
replace_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[](auto){ static int n = 0; return n++%5==0; },0);
```

не годится?

Еще вариант - сгенерировать последовательность единиц, каждый пятый - нуль, а потом применить `transform` с умножением.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan Ну, в лямбду передается ссылка на значение, так что считать, что `&Value` - ее итератор, и смотреть расстояние вроде как непереносимо?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Первый вариант работает корректно. Лямбда-ф-ции классная штука все таки). Заменил только auto на bool, а то ругалось. Второе я так понял сделать последовательность единиц и потом каждое умножить на рандомное число? Можно и так, по моему работать будет медленнее на много.

Comment: @Nazar019 Ну, примерно так. Понятно, что медленнее, но зато сразу много алгоритмов можно использовать - мало ли что преподу больше понравится :)

Comment: Предикаты не должны иметь состояний. Только `for_each` позволяет использовать функтор с состоянием. Простой пример, что будет, если авторы библиотеки сделают перебор элементов задом наперед? А если в 2 потока?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb `replace_if` не может задом наперёд, т.к. принимает `ForwardIterator`. Предикат состояние иметь может, но из-за возможного копирования функционального объекта, это состояние может "съехать". Можно запретить копирование, и если сборка прошла успешно, то проблемы быть не должно, т.к. кол-во вызовов предиката в `replace_if` равно кол-ву элементов. Вот чего точно не должен делать предикат, так это менять элемент. А насчёт потоков есть отдельные перегрузки алгоритмов, не думаю, что дефолтная версия может допускать распараллеливание, хотя однозначного запрета в стандарте я не нашёл.

Comment: @alexolut что если replace_if пройдется с помощью ForwardIterator вперед, запомнит данные, и затем в обратном порядке вызовет предикат.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan то это будет уже не тот C++, который мы знаем.

Comment: @alexolut, это я просто для примера написал. И я не думаю что в стандарте описано как именно должен быть реализован тот или иной алгоритм. Так что разработчики могут наколдовать каких-нибудь оптимизаций, вроде [супер быстрого поиска](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-efficient-generic-sorting-and-se/184403841). И тогда предикаты с состоянием могут все сломать.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb я сейчас конкретно про `replace_if`: кол-во вызовов предиката регламентировано, порядок обработки прямой из-за `ForwardIterator`. Если нет какого-то распараллеливания и состояние не сбрасывается при копировании (`static` не допускает какого-либо сброса) или копирования функционального объекта нет вовсе, то не вижу препятствий к работоспособности.

Answer (score 4):

Еще вариант (без использования static переменной-счетчика, что для некоторых ситуаций в мультипоточной программе может быть полезным):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

    std::replace_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [&v](const auto& e) {
        return ((&e - &v[0]) % 5) == 0;
    }, 0);

    for (auto i : v)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Из стандартных алгоритмов только один позволяет использовать функтор с состоянием. Это `std::for_each`. Таким образом переносимый вариант выглядит так:

```
struct Replace{
    int counter = 0;
    template<class T>
    void operator()(T &value){
        ++counter;
        if(counter == 5){
            counter = 0;
            value = 0;
        }
    }
};


std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), Replace());
```

**PS**: Если вы получили эту задачу в школе/в универе/на собеседовании, то скорее всего это вопрос с подвохом. Спрашивающий хочет подловить вас на незнании требований алгоритмов к функторам. Если эта проблема возникла сама собой, то проще всего будет сделать это при помощи обычного `for`:

```
for(int i = 5; i < v.size(); i+=5){
    v[i] = 0;
}
```

Я сам большой любитель stl, но нужно смотреть правде в глаза, для этой задачи обычный цикл проще:)

Comment: так как я, пока что, не очень разбираюсь, то подскажите пожалуйста, что имеется ввиду под переносимостью?

Comment: @Nazar019, В данном контексте я имел ввиду "будет компилироваться разными компиляторами и одинаково работать". Если ваш код нарушает какое-то правило стандарта, то вполне может быть, что при смене компилятора(а то и просто так) программа станет работать неправильно.